# EMF (OCL) concatenate two enumerations into one

Tags: java, enumeration, modeling, eclipse-emf, anchor-modeling

I wonder if EMF has a possibility to concatenate two enumerations into one?
I am building model representing card game, and I have two enumerations of Ranks and Suits in class Card. I would like to create combined enumeration in class Deck. Is there any way to approach that?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: This might be solution: Add to your model object a derived property or and operation that returns the desired type of iterable. Write normal Java code that implements the derived property.